# How to convert an int to a little endian byte array?

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

I have this function in C# to convert a little endian byte array to an integer number:

```
int LE2INT(byte[] data)
{
  return (data[3] << 24) | (data[2] << 16) | (data[1] << 8) | data[0];
}
```

Now I want to convert it back to little endian..
Something like

```
byte[] INT2LE(int data)
{
  // ...
}
```

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just reverse it, <strike>Note that this this code (like the other) works only on a little Endian machine.</strike> (edit - that was wrong, since this code returns LE by definition)

```
  byte[] INT2LE(int data)
  {
     byte[] b = new byte[4];
     b[0] = (byte)data;
     b[1] = (byte)(((uint)data >> 8) & 0xFF);
     b[2] = (byte)(((uint)data >> 16) & 0xFF);
     b[3] = (byte)(((uint)data >> 24) & 0xFF);
     return b;
  }
```

Comment: Why would your example work only on a little-endian machine?  AFAIK the bit shift method should be endian-agnostic.

Comment: @John, I'm pretty sure you're code works fine whether the code runs on a big- or little-endian architecture.  In either case, b[0] is the lowest order byte, b[1] is the next-lowest order byte, and so on.

Comment: My mistake, since this code returns LE rather than the natural byte order of the underlying cpu, it will work on all architectures. I'll remove the incorrect text.

Comment: According to the ECMA-335 standard the conversion from uint to byte (instruction conv.i1) means simply zeroing the most signficant bytes. Therefore, the "& 0xFF" part is excessively.

Answer (score 34):

The `BitConverter` class can be used for this, and of course, it can also be used on both little and big endian systems.

Of course, you'll have to keep track of the *endianness* of your data. For communications for instance, this would be defined in your protocol.

You can then use the `BitConverter` class to convert a data type into a byte array and vice versa, and then use the `IsLittleEndian` flag to see if you need to convert it on your system or not.

The `IsLittleEndian` flag will tell you the *endianness* of the system, so you can use it as follows:

This is from the MSDN page on the `BitConverter` class.

```
  int value = 12345678; //your value
  //Your value in bytes... in your system's endianness (let's say: little endian)
  byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(value);
  //Then, if we need big endian for our protocol for instance,
  //Just check if you need to convert it or not:
  if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
     Array.Reverse(bytes); //reverse it so we get big endian.
```

You can find the full article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx).

Hope this helps anyone coming here :)

Answer (score 9):

Just do it in reverse:

```
result[3]= (data >> 24) & 0xff;
result[2]= (data >> 16) & 0xff;
result[1]= (data >> 8)  & 0xff;
result[0]=  data        & 0xff;
```

Answer (score 3):

Could you use the [BitConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx) class?  It will only work on little-endian hardware I believe, but it should handle most of the heavy lifting for you.

The following is a contrived example that illustrates the use of the class:

```
if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
{
    int someInteger = 100;
    byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(someInteger);
    int convertedFromBytes = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
BitConverter.GetBytes(1000).Reverse<byte>().ToArray();
```

Comment: Could you please explain why this would help?

Comment: I am pretty sure that this is in case of Big Endian machine.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're actually doing, you could rely on letting the framework handle the details of endianness for you by using [IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/653kcke1.aspx) and the corresponding reverse function. Then just use the BitConverter class to go to and from byte arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`BinaryPrimitives`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.binary.binaryprimitives?view=net-6.0) in `System.Buffers.Binary`, it has helper methods for reading and writing all .net primitives in both little and big endian form.

```
byte[] IntToLittleEndian(int data)
{
  var output = new byte[sizeof(int)];
  BinaryPrimitives.WriteInt32LittleEndian(output, data);
  return output;
}
```

```
int LittleEndianToInt(byte[] data)
{
  return BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt32LittleEndian(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static string decimalToHexLittleEndian(int _iValue, int _iBytes)
    {
        string sBigEndian = String.Format("{0:x" + (2 * _iBytes).ToString() + "}", _iValue);
        string sLittleEndian = "";

        for (int i = _iBytes - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            sLittleEndian += sBigEndian.Substring(i * 2, 2);
        }

        return sLittleEndian;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this if you don't want to use new heap allocations:

```
public static void Int32ToFourBytes(Int32 number, out byte b0, out byte b1, out byte b2, out byte b3)
{
    b3 = (byte)number;
    b2 = (byte)(((uint)number >> 8) & 0xFF);
    b1 = (byte)(((uint)number >> 16) & 0xFF);
    b0 = (byte)(((uint)number >> 24) & 0xFF);
}
```