# Converting integer ip to ipaddress object. String ip is reversed?

Tags: c#, string

I'm deserializing data from a web page generated by php that is using ip2long(). However, when I try to make a new ip address by using the integer value in the constructor of IPAddress the dotted version of the ip address is in reverse order?

ex:

4.3.2.1 should really be 1.2.3.4

Any ideas of how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like someone is using [little-endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) and someone is using network byte order (big-endian) for the packed value. For instance the *octect sequence* compromising an integer, `AA,BB,CC,DD` in LE is `DD,CC,BB,AA` in BE/NBO -- a nice symmetrical reverse!

Since the [IPAddress(Int64) constructor documentations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13180abx.aspx) says:

> > The Int64 value is assumed to be in network byte order.

I would *imagine* that `ip2long` in PHP is generating a value in little-endian. Good thing `IPAddress` also takes `byte[]` for the constructor, now get those elbows greasy... just pass the bytes in the "correct" order.

Happy coding.

---

The code at [How to convert an int to a little endian byte array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350099/how-to-convert-an-int-to-a-little-endian-byte-array) should give some ideas.

---

Or, as Josh points out, there is a [HostToNetworkOrder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdx10bbd.aspx) method to do this.

Comment: Thanks. I found that IPAddress actually has a method for converting from host to network byte order.

Answer (score 0):

use `long2ip()` to reverse the process of `ip2long()`

```
<?php
// make sure IPs are valid. also converts a non-complete IP into
// a proper dotted quad as explained below.
$ip = long2ip(ip2long("127.0.0.1")); // "127.0.0.1"
$ip = long2ip(ip2long("10.0.0")); // "10.0.0.0"
$ip = long2ip(ip2long("10.0.256")); // "10.0.1.0"
?>
```

you shouldn't really have any problems after all it's a standard in php

Comment: Yes. While not explicit it sounds like the decoding is done in C# ... somewhere ... for some reason.

Comment: I don't have any control over the output of the php page. They are giving the integer value from ip2long() for me to use.