# How to convert Int to 8-byte little-endian

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

i already found this question: [How to convert an int to a little endian byte array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350099/how-to-convert-an-int-to-a-little-endian-byte-array)

Is there a way to convert the integer into a byte[8] instead of a byte[4] array?

Comment: I think it always should be a `byte[4]` since LE uses 4 bytes.

Comment: In C# `int` is 4 bytes. Where do you want to get the other 4 bytes from?

Comment: so when i want byte[8], i need to fill them with 0x00?

Comment: Just cast to `long` before converting to LE. "Filling" with zeroes would make any negative number a different positive number.

Comment: ok so, when i use long (instead int) from the beginning i will get byte[8]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just cast the `int` to `long` before converting to Little Endian.

"Filling" with zeroes would make any negative number a different positive number.