# Convert array of Ints into array of Little-Endian Bytes in C#

Tags: c#, endianness

I need to convert a large array of ints into an array of their little endian byte representations. Is there a function that converts the array or is the only way to loop through and "manually" convert each one.

Comment: [`.Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-6.0)

Comment: Do you expect he output to be `byte[]` or `byte[][]`?

Comment: Please show an example of what your input is and what your expected output is. And also show what you have already tried

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert an int to a little endian byte array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350099/how-to-convert-an-int-to-a-little-endian-byte-array)

Comment: Whether you use a loop or `linq` at some level you have to loop through your array

Comment: Are you running this on a little-endian machine, or must the solution be endian-agnostic?

Comment: Note that `BinaryPrimitives` was added since that linked answer was written

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you could do is use the [EndianBitConverter](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EndianBitConverter/) project from Nuget.  It does what it says on the tin and provides a way of converting to either big-endian or little-endian.

Once you have got it installed, you can write code like this:

```
var intList = new List<int> { 91233, 67278, 22345, 45454, 23449 };
            
foreach ( var n in intList)
{
    var result1 = EndianBitConverter.LittleEndian.GetBytes(n);
    var result2 = EndianBitConverter.BigEndian.GetBytes(n);
}
```

If you want to do it as a 1 liner, then perhaps something like this:

```
var intList = new List<int> { 91233, 67278, 22345, 45454, 23449 };
var result = intList.Select(x => EndianBitConverter.LittleEndian.GetBytes(x)).ToList();
```